# multiply element in list

Tags: list, pandas, series

I have a list [1.05, 1.06, 1.08, 1.01, 1.29, 1.07, 1.06]
I want to make a function multiply any element i in the list by all next element i+1 until the end of the list.
Example: function(2), it will return the result of (1.08*1.01*1.29*1.07*1.06)

I found this, but it returns NoneType, so I can't then use the value returned by this function.
Thanks,

```
def multiply(j,n):
   total=1
   for i in range(j,len(n)):
      total*=n[i]
   if total is not None:
      print (total)
```

Comment: why pandas tag? `list` is `series` ?

Comment: Add "return total" to the end of your function so that it will return a value (though I'm not sure it's doing what you'd like it to do quite yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need `pandas` solution first select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) and then use [`prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.prod.html):

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
print (s)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64

print (s.iloc[2:])
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64

print (s.iloc[2:].prod())
12
```

But if need pure python, use solution from [Benjamin comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744783/multiply-element-in-list/40744858#comment68715230_40744783) - instead `print` - `return`:

```
m = [1,2,3,4]

def multiply(j,n):
   total=1
   for i in range(j,len(n)):
      total*=n[i]
   return total

print (multiply(2,m))
12
```

Comment: total is never None in this case, you can remove that `if` statement